# getting a particular data from the parent node

Tags: laravel, neoeloquent

I am new in neoeloquent. I have created some node which has some child nodes. But I can't figure out how do I get the data of the parent node from the child node?

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive relationship. In the Model, you just need to setup relationships as follows, assuming your keys are setup correctly. Then you can load the relationship using the `with('parent)` or `load('parent)` methods in your query.

Relationships:

```
//Node.php

public function children(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Node', 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function parent(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Node', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```